# PHP Regular Expression Help Needed

Tags: php, regex

can anyone please tell me why this simple regex is failing?

```
$blogurl = 'http://www.sirpi.org/2011/02/23/';
if(preg_match("/[0-9]\/[0-9]\/[0-9]\/$/", $blogurl)){
  echo "Bad URL\n";
}
```

Comment: It might help if you explained what this code is *supposed* to do. As it is, that regex will never match that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to be trying to test whether there are numbers in between `/` at the end of string.  For that you can use

```
$blogurl = 'http://www.sirpi.org/2011/02/23/';
if(preg_match("/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/$/", $blogurl)){
  echo "Bad URL\n";
}
```

the `+` means one or more.  Otherwise you are just matching against a single digit and the numbers there in the URL are not just single digits.

You can also use `\d` for digits instead of `[0-9]`:

```
$blogurl = 'http://www.sirpi.org/2011/02/23/';
if(preg_match("/\d+\/\d+\/\d+\/$/", $blogurl)){
  echo "Bad URL\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are matching this:

```
one of characters 0-9
a literal slash ("/")
one of characters 0-9
a literal slash ("/")
one of characters 0-9
a literal slash ("/")
end of string
```

You may want to match years that have more than one digit, similarly with months and days.

Answer (score 1):

```
/[0-9]\/[0-9]\/[0-9]\/$/
```

is looking for a

```
 [0-9] a single digit
 \/    followed by a /
 [0-9] a single digit
 \/    followed by a /
 [0-9] a single digit
 \/    followed by a /
 $     at the end of the string
```

Try

```
/[0-9]{1,4}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/$/
```

whic tests for the number of digits between each /

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]` matches a single digit. So this regex matches a single digit, a slash, a single digit, a slash, a single digit, a slash and and end of string.

So it would match `4/5/6/`, but not `11/22/33/`.

If you want to match one or more digits, you should use `[0-9]+`. You can also use `[0-9]*` if you wish to match zero or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

because you are searching for single digits. Try this:

```
"/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/$/"
```

Answer (score 0):

also, if you want the number of sub url things to be variable;

```
"/(\/[0-9]+)+\/?$/"
```

that is, at least one **/** followed by a string of numbers, and then an optional finishing **/**.

Looks like the urls are dates though from your example, so this probably isn't necessary.